# Unexpected error in cpp program?

Tags: c++, linux

I'm working on c++, following is my code:

test.h

```
char[] defaultSurname  = "salunke";
void in_dev(const char* name, char* surname = defaultSurname );
```

test.cpp

```
#include "test.h"
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

void in_dev(const char* name, char* surname)
{
    cout <<" surname id "<< surname << endl;
}

int main()
{
  in_dev("Balaji", "Patil");
  return 0;
}
```

but it gives following compilation errors:

```
test.h:1: error: expected unqualified-id before '[' token
test.h:9: error: 'defaultSurname' was not declared in this scope
```

How to resolve this errors?

Comment: [C++ Arrays](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/cplusplus/cpp_arrays.htm)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
char[] defaultSurname  = "salunke";
```

should be:

```
char defaultSurname[]  = "salunke";
```

When in doubt use the **[clockwise spiral rule](http://c-faq.com/decl/spiral.anderson.html)** and it should help.